# FQL: How to get other photos belonging to the same post?

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-fql, photo

```
SELECT created_time, like_info, share_count, message, attachment FROM stream WHERE post_id='119757088035616_862221027122548'
```

With this FQL-Query, i'm getting several information about one post inside the stream of a facebook-page. However, that single post could also be a single image inside an album of photos. Is there a way to catch every photo belonging to a post (which would be a new album, in this case)?

Comment: Your example has only one photo attached. What do you mean with new album in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all photos of the album the posted photo is in, try this FQL query:

```
select pid, aid, created, src from photo where aid in (SELECT attachment.media.photo.aid FROM stream WHERE post_id='119757088035616_862221027122548')
```

In case you just want the photo info, use this for example:

```
select pid, aid, created, src from photo where pid in (SELECT attachment.fb_object_id FROM stream WHERE post_id='119757088035616_862221027122548')
```